# Does $ f(A)^{°} \subseteq f(A^{°})$ hold in general for a continuous $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Given are two metric spaces $(X , d_X)$ , $(Y , d_Y)$ and a continuous function $f : X \rightarrow Y$.

For all subsets $A \subseteq X $, is $f(A)^{°} \subseteq f(A^{°})$ true?   ( ' $^{°}$ ' means interior)

My first thought was that $f(A^{°})$ is open because $A^{°}$ is. By definition of interior  $f(A)^{°}$  is the largest open subset of $f(A)$. So $f(A)^{°}$ can never be a subset of $f(A^{°})$, is that right?

I tried finding a counterexample but couldn't find an obvious one that came to mind. Anyone has an idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: $f(A)$ doesn't have to be open for an open set $A\subset X$. It's $f^{-1}(B)$ that is open, for an open set $B\subset Y$

Comment: Ah yes of course, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think of a function $f$ that takes the line $(-\infty,\infty)$ onto the unit circle $S^1$, where $f$ is one-to-one on an $[0,1]$ except at the endpoints, where $f(0) = f(1)$. For instance
$$f(t) = (\cos 2\pi t,\sin 2\pi t)$$
will do the job.

Let $A = [0,1]$.  Since $f(A) = S^1$ you also have $f(A)^\circ = S^1$.

On the other hand, $f(A^\circ)$ is missing a point of $S^1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just what I were looking for!